# Use cases for `A.__new__(B)` i.e. "using one class to make another" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I take

```py
A.__new__(B)
```

to mean "use the `A` object-creating method to make an (uninitialized) `B` object".

What are some use cases where I can/should use such abilities?

#### More details

The question is about *when could one use the `some_cls.__new__(some_other_cls)` capabilities*

But since responders claim that the very use of `__new__` is probably misled, I will show a situation where I'm (possibly misled) to think that using `__new__` might be a good idea.

The actual context is that of json-serializing `scikit-learn` models in such a way that an edge device can deserialize and run a target method (e.g. 'predict'). Two important aspects here: (1) `scikit-learn` estimator classes' `__init__` takes parameters concerning the fitting of a model, but the attributes needed to run the `predict` method are dynamically made in `fit` method, and (2) a light weight serialized model is preferable, and the edge device is probably running a light weight function (not the original `scikit-learn` method.

I hope the code below illustrates this situation sufficiently faithfully:

```py
class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, greet):
        self.greet = greet
        
    def fit(self, this):
        self.greet_this_ = self.greet + ' ' + this
        
    def __call__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'greet_this_'):
            raise ValueError("Greeter not fit")
        return self.greet_this_

obj = Greeter("hello")
obj.fit('world')
assert obj() == 'hello world'
```

Here's some serialization code:

```py
import json

def serialize(obj, needed_attrs):
    return json.dumps({a: getattr(obj, a) for a in needed_attrs})

class MethodLess: ...

def deserialize(obj_json, cls=MethodLess):
    obj = cls.__new__(cls)  # make the (unintialized) instance
    # Note: couldn't do obj = cls() because cls might need some inputs
    
    for k, v in json.loads(obj_json).items():  # fill it with it's attributes
        setattr(obj, k, v)

    return obj

obj_json = serialize(obj, ['greet_this_'])
deserialized_obj = deserialize(obj_json, cls=Greeter)
assert deserialized_obj() == 'hello world' == obj()
```

But we don't even need the original class, just the method we need to call.

```py
class MinimalGreeter:
    def __call__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'greet_this_'):
            raise ValueError("Greeter not fit")
        return self.greet_this_
    
obj_json = serialize(obj, ['greet_this_'])
deserialized_obj = deserialize(obj_json, cls=MinimalGreeter)
assert deserialized_obj() == 'hello world' == obj()
```

Equivalently, in functional form...

```py
def call(self):
    if not hasattr(self, 'greet_this_'):
        raise ValueError("Greeter not fit")
    return self.greet_this_
    
obj_json = serialize(obj, ['greet_this_'])
deserialized_obj = deserialize(obj_json, cls=MethodLess)
assert call(deserialized_obj) == 'hello world' == call(obj) == obj()
```

Comment: If `A` defines `__new__` but `B` (which inherits from `A`) doesn't, this is exactly what gets called for you when you instantiate `B`. There's little reason do make such a call explicitly (although this is effectively what gets called, if you define `B.__new__` and use `super`, with `super().__new__(cls, ...)` )

Comment: In the common case, when you aren't defining your own `__new__` methods, `object.__new__` is ultimately being called with your class as its first argument.

Comment: +1 @chepner, because informative to those who don't know. But what I'm looking for is where this ability might be useful. Being able to call `__new__` directly is useful to me in situations where I need a particular instance (with all it's methods), but the `__init__` doesn't satisfy my initialization need. tldr; happens in `scikit-learn` where `__init__` sets "learner params", but after fitting you get extra attributes you need to `predict`.

Comment: Can you provide an exact example of what you mean? I suspect there is a better option than calling `__new__` explicitly.

Comment: @chepner. Done. I updated the post.

Comment: Your `deserialize` function would work better as a class method that can extract the necessary values to pass to `__init__` from the JSON (or fail trying). At the very least, `deserialize` should be a wrapper around a class-specific method. Either way, `deserialize` itself is not responsible for creating an instance or knowing how to properly initialize it: that remains the purview of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any reason why you would want to call `__new__` directly. But if you are asking why you might return a different type from `__new__`, one example would be to return a proxy object or a different implementation based on what constructor arguments are passed. In other words it can be used as an alternative to the factory pattern.

EDIT: An example, as requested:

```
class _StandardSolver:
    def solve(self, x):
        print('Using standard algorithm')
        return x + 1

class _SpecialSolver:
    def solve(self, x):
        print('Using special algorithm')
        return x * x  # Imagine this algorithm is much more complicated, relying on a lot of class state, etc.

class ComplicatedProblemSolver:
    def __new__(cls, use_special_algo, *args, **kwargs):
        if use_special_algo:
            return _SpecialSolver(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return _StandardSolver(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solver = ComplicatedProblemSolver(use_special_algo=True)
    print('Solution:', solver.solve(5))
```

Comment: I describe my "reason" for calling `__new__` directly in a comment below my question. As for your factory pattern mention, could you provide details/code on what you mean?

Comment: @thorwhalen Example added.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I don't see the `A.__new__(B)` pattern here. That is, where one uses the `__new__` of one class `A` to make an (uninitialized) instance of *another* class `B`.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the details of how you (de)serialize an object in the class itself. Then deserialization can decode the JSON blob and extract the values necessary to be passed to `__init__`. For example:

```
import json


class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, greet):
        self.greet = greet
        
    def fit(self, this):
        self.greet_this_ = self.greet + ' ' + this
        
    def __call__(self):
        if not hasattr(self, 'greet_this_'):
            raise ValueError("Greeter not fit")
        return self.greet_this_

    def to_json(self):
        return json.dumps({'greet': self.greet, 'greet_this_': self.greet_this_)

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, obj_json):
        d = json.loads(obj_json)
        obj = cls(d['greet'])
        obj.fit(d['greet_this_'])
        return obj
        

obj = Greeter("hello")
obj.fit('world')
assert obj() == 'hello world'


obj_json = obj.to_json()
deserialized_obj = Greeter.from_json(obj_json)
assert deserialized_obj() == 'hello world' == obj()
```

Comment: Sorry @chepner but (1) the question is about what might be the uses of `A.__new__(B)` (you're just proposing a different solution to my "why ever use `__new__` in the first place) and (2) your example code is EXACTLY what we have been doing and are precisely trying to move away from because it's not dynamic/flexible enough for our needs.

Comment: Why do you think there *are* uses for `A.__new__(B)` as opposed to not calling it explicitly in the first place? What about this is too inflexible?

Comment: In my experience, if there's a way, people find a use (even if that use wasn't intended by the mechanism. Obviously, if anyone _has_ found some utility to `A.__new__(B)`, no one that read my question has encountered it yet. So at least I have an estimate of rareness.

Comment: As to what is inflexible about our previous "include the serializer in the class" way of doing things, I don't know if I want to get into those details (more than I have already in the "The actual context is..." paragraph of my extended post). Additionally it's not the subject of my question. If I feel inspired one day, I might just write another post about that so SOers can throw stuff at it.